# What is wrong with my use of the Compass @font-face mixin?

Tags: css, sass, font-face, compass-sass

I'm including the Open Sans font in my website by using SASS and the Compass [font-face mixin](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/font_face/) as follows:

```
@include font-face("Open Sans",
    font-files(
        "../fonts/opensans-light/OpenSans-Light-webfont.woff",
        "../fonts/opensans-light/OpenSans-Light-webfont.ttf",
        "../fonts/opensans-light/OpenSans-Light-webfont.svg#open_sanslight"
    ),
    "../fonts/opensans-light/OpenSans-Light-webfont.eot", 200);

@include font-face("Open Sans",
    font-files(
        "../fonts/opensans-regular/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.woff",
        "../fonts/opensans-regular/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.ttf",
        "../fonts/opensans-regular/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.svg#open_sansregular"
    ),
    "../fonts/opensans-regular/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.eot", normal);

@include font-face("Open Sans",
    font-files(
        "../fonts/opensans-semibold/OpenSans-Semibold-webfont.woff",
        "../fonts/opensans-semibold/OpenSans-Semibold-webfont.ttf",
        "../fonts/opensans-semibold/OpenSans-Semibold-webfont.svg#open_sanssemibold"
    ),
    "../fonts/opensans-semibold/OpenSans-Semibold-webfont.eot", 600);

@include font-face("Open Sans",
    font-files(
        "../fonts/opensans-bold/OpenSans-Bold-webfont.woff",
        "../fonts/opensans-bold/OpenSans-Bold-webfont.ttf",
        "../fonts/opensans-bold/OpenSans-Bold-webfont.svg#open_sansbold"
    ),
    "../fonts/opensans-bold/OpenSans-Bold-webfont.eot", bold);
```

I formerly just used CSS3 @font-face as follows:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    src: url('../fonts/opensans-light/OpenSans-Light-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/opensans-light/OpenSans-Light-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/opensans-light/OpenSans-Light-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/opensans-light/OpenSans-Light-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/opensans-light/OpenSans-Light-webfont.svg#open_sanslight') format('svg');
    font-weight: 200;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    src: url('../fonts/opensans-regular/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/opensans-regular/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/opensans-regular/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/opensans-regular/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/opensans-regular/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.svg#open_sansregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    src: url('../fonts/opensans-semibold/OpenSans-Semibold-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/opensans-semibold/OpenSans-Semibold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/opensans-semibold/OpenSans-Semibold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/opensans-semibold/OpenSans-Semibold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/opensans-semibold/OpenSans-Semibold-webfont.svg#open_sanssemibold') format('svg');
    font-weight: 600;
    font-style: normal;
}


@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    src: url('../fonts/opensans-bold/OpenSans-Bold-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/opensans-bold/OpenSans-Bold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/opensans-bold/OpenSans-Bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/opensans-bold/OpenSans-Bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/opensans-bold/OpenSans-Bold-webfont.svg#open_sansbold') format('svg');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Which worked perfectly well. And at the top of my scss file I have: `@import "compass/css3/font-face";`

Comment: Is there an error?  What is the error?  If I'm not mistaken, the path to the font files is supposed to be relative to the fonts directory (check your config.rb).

Comment: None of the text is showing up. config.rb doesn't show anything relevant.

Comment: I agree with @cimmanon. It looks like your urls are relative to the **css file** - but they need to be relative to the **fonts folder** instead - and that is a setting in `config.rb`. Just remove `../fonts/` from each URL and you should be fine. (even with font-face breaking, though, the text shouldn't disappear - it should just be un-styled)

Comment: Removing `../fonts/` didn't seem to do anything, unfortunately. The text is still disappearing (and yes, disappearing, it seems to be setting the alpha value to 0). Also, hi, I really appreciate your work.

Comment: Are you sure the alpha setting isn't coming from somewhere else?

Comment: Where's the generated CSS?

Answer (score 8):

Have look to your config.rb file would help but, assuming there nothing relative in it, the generated path in your css should look like this

`/{css_dir}/../fonts/opensans-semibold/OpenSans-Semibold-webfont.eot`

In your ***config.rb***  use  `relative_assets = true` and set `fonts_dir = "../fonts"` otherwise by default your generated url will start with ```fonts/````.

You can then use `@include font-face(` as you did but by discarding "../fonts" in your urls.

If the folder containing the compiled css is outside your sass project then I recommend you to use `http_fonts_path` to avoid any mistake in urls. It will allow you to specify an absolute url starting from your app or website `DocumentRoot` directory.

In the following example fonts files are placed in '/static/fonts' :

***config.rb***

```
http_fonts_path = "/static/fonts"  
# relative_assets = true
# replace static by your public asset folder path
```

**!! comment `relative_assets = true` if you use `http_fonts_path` !!**

***my.scss****

```
@include font-face("Open Sans", font-files( "opensans-semibold/OpenSans-Semibold-webfont.woff", "opensans-semibold/OpenSans-Semibold-webfont.ttf" ), "opensans-semibold/OpenSans-Semibold-webfont.eot" );
```

Run `compass clean` after each change to *config.rb*

Comment: Still if @font-face doesn't work you should still see your text with the default font-family.

Comment: as the owner of the question hasn't answered, I'd like to say that my problems with font-face paths were solved following @svassr instructions, thanks!